# C++ Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in dynamic array of vectors

Tags: c++, vector, stdvector

The piece of code says something like:
(Code is trying to fill an appearance array  till 100)
I fix size of array of vectors in arrayOne[0].numberOfThings because I know that it is the max number of items it can contain you can treat it like an known integer.

```
int max = 100;
int maxNThings = arrayOne[0].numberOfThings; //Integer that I know and I pickit as the max for dynamic array
    vector<Thing>* appearanceArrayOfNumThings;
    appearanceArrayOfNumThings= new vector<Thing>[maxNThings];
    for (int i = 0; i<max;i++){
        int currentNumberOfThings = arrayOne[i].numberOfThings;
        appearanceArrayOfNumThings[currentNumberOfThings ].push_back(arrayOne[i]);
    }
```

I am having

> Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

inside the for statement, line `appearanceArrayOfNumThings[currentNumberOfThings ].push_back(arrayOne[i]);`

And I am thinking if it is because vector behaviour that I dont know.

Can you give me any clue or you seeing something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `vector<Thing>*` is pretty much always wrong. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: To make dynamic array of vectors

Comment: A `vector` *is* a dynamic array. And you can make a vector of vectors if you really have to

Comment: @TonyK you can think it is an integer. Is where I know I have the max num of items so im using it like that. I know array content so there is an integer there. I specified that but I know it can be missunderstood.:)

Comment: `std::vector` is a dynamic array.  If you want a dynamic array of vectors you just use `std::vector<std::vector<element_type>>`

Comment: @UnholySheep I will try vector of vector, but I thought about it cause clarify myself when I want to insert a value on specific index of the array.

Comment: The code in your question is incomplete, as some of the variables are not defined or explained in the code snippet, specifically line #2 `arrayOne[0]` tells us nothing about the type or capacity of `arrayOne`.

Comment: Why the manual memory management?

Comment: "will try vector of vector, but I thought about it cause clarify myself when I want to insert a value on specific index of the array" - that does not make *any* sense. What are you trying to say?

Comment: Important: what are you actually trying to do? It is presently unclear.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i mean in essence {arrayOne[i] = whatever} looks more readable for me that {v.insert(v.begin()+i, whatever)}. Nothing special at the end but wanted to give it try and I have found this error. Must exist a way to reach it behaviour. At the end I think vector of vector is the easy way. :) Cheers and thanks all. You helped me a bunch! Tzalumen I specified it in what I wrote since minute one and a bit later in my comment. arrayOne[0]..nthings is an integer I know.

Comment: @FooBarExtension Glad you seem to have solved your problem. Still not quite sure what you are saying.. but be that as it may.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I can solve it witha vector of vector. But I know there exists a solution with a dynamic array of vectors directly. I wanted it solution only because I find it more readable inside a for statement. If I use an array I can do arrayOne[i] = someVector. Instead of someVector1.insert(someVector1.begin()+i, someVector2). It is just for readability since also vector as you pointed is a dynamic array :)

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: @FooBarExtension `arrayOne[i] = whatever` is still possible with vector... `vector::insert` resizes the array, the `operator=` is the same for both vector and arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should use a debugger, you would have spotted the bug instantly.

Second, `new vector<Thing>[maxNThings]` is a **bad** idea. ***don't do that***. Use `std::vector<std::vector<Thing>>` at least. A vector of struct containing a vector is clearer in my opinion.

Using a vector of vector, you can use `.at()` which would have told your error.

---

This code will always invoke undefined behaviour.

```
int maxNThings = arrayOne[0].numberOfThings;
```

Let's say for a moment that this number is `12`.

```
appearanceArrayOfNumThings = new vector<Thing>[maxNThings]; // 12
```

This create an array of 12 vectors. Indexable from `0` to `11`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < max ;i++){
    // ...
}
```

For the first iteration, `i` is equal to `0`. Let's continue.

```
// i == 0
int currentNumberOfThings = arrayOne[i].numberOfThings;
```

At this point, `arrayOne[i]` is the same value as `arrayOne[0]`, since `i` is equal to `0`. So `currentNumberOfThings` is equal to `12`, which is equal to `maxNThings`.

```
appearanceArrayOfNumThings[currentNumberOfThings ]
```

This access `appearanceArrayOfNumThings[12]`, which is out of bound since `appearanceArrayOfNumThings` is indexable from `0` to `11`. You enter UB land. Here's your bug.

It will always fail for any value of `maxNThings`.

Comment: Solved it with vectorof vector and I notice now the bug you comment. Thank you @GuillaumeRacicot